# Git - setting up architecture

Tags: git

My question is about the structure/architecture of a git project.

This is essentially what we will be working with:

A project, (code named Titan) that we are currently working on, where the project retrieves and modifies data from several different sources. Titan is the umbrella for all of the different sources and will someday be used to produce reports using the different sources.

In this example, let's say Titan will utilize 5 different, independent sources, named as follows:
Source A
Source B
Source C
Source D
Source E

Again, every source is completely unique, and the etl that is done on the data from each source is release into production independently of any of the other sources.

With all of the above stated -
Given the data transformations are unique for each source, and their releases are independent from one another , is it better design to:
A). Stick with having one master branch that is normally the default of Git?
B). Have numerous masters, one per Source, as they are independently worked on and released into production?

Any help that can given would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: If fully independent, 5 repositories. If sharing some common code, one master. Branches are not usually meant for this kind of usage.

Comment: Sounds like you might need submodules.